# SQL Server stored procedure can insert, cannot delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 stored procedures that I make a call to in my MVC app. First one adds rows to db, second one deletes some rows. 
Both the procedures work fine on the local machine. But on the remote server only Insert works. When I try to delete rows, I get error: An error occurred while processing your request.

Comment: How do you expect us to give you a solution? At least show the code!

Comment: @HoneyBadger Everything is OK on the local machine, it means that the code is OK, I'm expected that problem can be in user roles, security or something else

Comment: And yet you give no information about the machines....

Comment: @HoneyBadger On the remote machine I use Windows-server-2012-r2, local - windows 7. On the both I use SQL Server 2014

Comment: are working same database? connection string?

Comment: @reds yes, everything the same

Comment: Are stored proc updated to your server deployment pc?

Comment: @reds yes, but for me it's strange that insert operation is working, but delete is not

Comment: Run the exact same stored procedure call directly on the server using the same login information. You should get a better error message from SQL server"

Comment: @PeterHahndorf thanks, I've got a detailed error and fixed my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really you need to show a detailed error message. If you turn off custom errors on your live site, you should get a detailed stack trace of the error, which you should post here to help people diagnose your problem.

My guess is though that it's probably permissions based, as one of the stored procedures works. Ensure that the database user has execute permissions on the other stored procedure. It sounds obvious, but also check that the second stored procedure is present on the live site too.